# Redirect User to his has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

My `User`has_one `Dashboard`

After their sign_up, I create a `Dashboard` and want to redirect user to his dashboard.
I'm using Devise

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  @dash =  Dashboard.create(:user_id => current_user.id)
  User.update(current_user.id, :name => 'Samuel')
  '/dashboards/#{@dash.id}' 
end
```

It creates dashboard fine, but redirects me to `dashboards/#{@dash.id}`
I've tryied others methods without success.
How can I get this dashboard ID and redirect User to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double quotes for string interpolation.

```
'/dashboards/#{@dash.id}'
```

Should be:

```
"/dashboards/#{@dash.id}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
redirect_to dashboard_path(@dash.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes

```
"/dashboards/#{@dash.id}"
```